# Why is Bob H's answer here deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

[The question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59727/has-trump-ever-explained-why-he-as-incumbent-president-is-unable-to-stop-the-a). Bob H has written two answers, one of which is hidden because it's marked as spam/abusive. The other isn't, but is still deleted. Why? A mod (JJJ) has already removed the latter part of the answer, and I don't see why the remainder is inappropriate.

**Edit**: the answer appears to have been un-deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user flagged this answer as a duplicate of an answer which was previously deleted by another moderator. At first glance that appeared to be true. Trying to circumvent moderator or community decisions to delete content by just reposting it is an absolute no-go in my opinion, so I deleted it too.

But then I noticed that the same moderator who deleted the first answer then edited the second answer and removed the section which apparently lead them to delete the first. I didn't want to override the decision of the other moderator without good reason, so I corrected my action and undeleted the second version of the answer.

According to [the timeline](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/59792/timeline), the answer was deleted for 2 minutes and 11 seconds.